# Get TinyMCE Print event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

How can I get the tinyMCE print button event?

I want to do something after clicking on print. 
For exxample:

```
if(editor.print() == 'Finish'){ alert('Test'); }
```

Does anyone know if it is possible?

Comment: I don't see any events related to printing here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could register for the [ExecCommand](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/) event.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: 'print',
  init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
    editor.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
      if (e.command === 'mcePrint') {
        alert('Print');
      }
    });
  }
});
```